# Where do I put a folder that is used in my C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm planning on my C# application having a folder called `Data` that is reused whenever the program is launched. I put it in the root of my Visual Studio solution which causes it to be where you see below

```
 MyProject (File folder)
     bin (File folder)
         Debug (File folder)
             MyProject (Application)
             .
             .
     Data
     obj  
          .
          . 
     .
     .
```

after the project is built ... but I'm guessing I'd want it where the actual application is, right? Or is it proper for me to instead have a "Create if doesn't exists" for that folder in my application? Sorry if this is considered a subjective question.

Comment: So its more a good design question. I would say it depends. From what it looks like the Data folder you have created in the solution explorer. This means that in this case you just have source code in it.  From what you mention you want it to be used by the application?

Comment: @Thomas No source code in it. The application merely uses it as a repository for files

Comment: tnx. Created an answer with that in mind (have almost guessed so). Normally that folder is not copied automatically. You need to put a file into it with copy always property set to true if you want it to be copied into the solution (if there is another option via solution explorer for folders I'm not aware of it). Put that info also into the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you may check it at the start of the program if it doesn't exist then you may create it. 
Right click on your SOlution in visual studio>> Add new project>> Under other project types>> Choose>> Setup and deployment >> Visual Studio installer >> Set up project.

Setup projects are important in many cases, when you need to make any changes for first time installment or need to modify registry, need to copy some data folder or other settings for the first time.

2) Create a setup project and in your setup project you may create that data folder, which will be created when user will install the application.

I would prefer to use both option to avoid any issue in future.

Comment: What is a setup project?

Comment: Right click on your SOlution in visual studio>> Add new project>> Under other project types>> Choose>> Setup and deployment >> Visual Studio installer >> Set up project.

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like in your example the data folder you created in your application/solution explorer. So far so good but it wont ever be created inside your project.

You have 2 options if you want it to be in the same directory as your application.

1. You create a .txt file or whatever you want to put into it later on in the solution explorer and say "copy always" in the properties
2. Is you create your folder manually inside your program. The base location of your program is usually `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. Thus you could use `Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + folderName)`.

For 2 this could be done on each run on the program (if the directory does not exist yet OR on setup of the program if you have a special setup routine).

As far as I'm aware all of these variants are legit and are dependent on your exact use case and personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing I'd want it where the actual application is, right?

**NO!** Let's say you eventually bundle this program into an installer the puts it in it's own Program Files folder. *Standard Users do not have write access to anything under the Program Files folder!*. You just forced your program to require Administrator rights every time it runs.

Instead, you need to put your data folder in the Application Data special folder:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Comment: Are you sure about the admin rights there? I mean if you put something into the program folders directly ... yes. But I'm not aware that you need admin rights if you put something into a sub folder of the programs folder (thus the folder where the application.exe resides in).

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure. Unless you build your own custom installer action to change permissions on the folder, your application's program files folder will still require administrator privileges for write access.